# Use items in Json data as text

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have some data being pulled back from an entity framework stored procedure and want the page to iterate through the set and assign the value to a different div element.

I've got this on the page:

(Tried 2 different ways below -- KValueText2/3 are column headers returned in the query)

```
var KId2 = $('#Selector :selected').val()
        $.get("/Home/getValTitles", { HeadID: KId2 }, function (data) {
            for (var idx in data.result) {
                var results = data.results[idx];
                $('#ValueText1').html(results(0));
                $('#ValueText2').text = results(idx).KValueText2;
                $('#ValueText3').text = results(idx).KValueText3;
            }
        })
```

...and on the controller:

```
public JsonResult getValTitles(string HeadID)
        {
            var temp2 = et.usp_Read_K_Value_Titles(HeadID);
            return Json(temp2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

How do I assign each of the items within the returned data to a different element on the page?

JSON data returned:

```
[
  {
    "KValueText1":"Calls",
    "KValueText2":"Total",
    "KValueText3":‌​null
  }
]
```

Comment: show us an example which demonstrates the structure of the "data" object please.

Comment: @ADyson do you mean the data expected to be returned from the DB?

Comment: yes. the "data" object that is returned in `function (data)`. Show us the structure of it. (You can get it by doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`)

Comment: Whereabouts would I put that line and see the return? Before the for(var...?

Comment: just above your "for" line would work. Then check your browser console for the result (press F12 to open the Developer tools on most desktop browsers)

Comment: JSON data returned: [{"KValueText1":"Calls","KValueText2":"Total","KValueText3":null}]

Comment: Sorry not sure how best to post that!

Comment: edit the question and include it! I'll do it for you, to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data is an array with one element, which is an object. It's a bit of an odd structure, because from your code it looks like you're only interested in the one object (since you're assigning the values directly to specific elements). Anyway here's how to read it:

```
var KId2 = $('#Selector :selected').val()
$.get("/Home/getValTitles", { HeadID: KId2 }, function (data) {
   $('#ValueText1').html(data[0].KValueText1);
   $('#ValueText2').text(data[0].KValueText2);
   $('#ValueText3').text(data[0].KValueText3);
})
```

N.B. If you can change the return value to be a single object instead of an array, you can get rid of the `[0]` on each line and just access the properties directly. (The `[0]` is used to access the first index of the array. You could also use a `for` loop but it's pointless since you only have one element.)

Comment: Perfect thank you! And thanks for editing/being patient... still new to this site and getting used to how it works. My code now works

Answer (score 0):

Since idx is the looping variable it will contain the json array element currently being processed inside the loop

hence you can use

```
          $('#ValueText2').text = idx.KValueText2;
            $('#ValueText3').text = idx.KValueText3;
```

to get the value of the columns KValueText2, KValueText3